# (if/else if) com check box

Tags: php, html, if, else

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho uma estrutura de decisão que checa o o check box.

Porém, quando seleciono as duas caixas, o código ainda sim executa os comandos que checa se apenas uma das caixas foi selecionada, e com razão, pois em meus IFs eu apenas procuro se a palavra está contida. Com o código fica mais claro entender:

```
if(empty($array_membro)){
    echo("Você não selecionou nenhum membro.");
}else{
    if(in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"]) && in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){
        echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
        Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
        <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
        </form>";
        $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE (membros.id = 1 OR membros.id = 2)');
        for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
            include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
        }
    }if(in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"])){
        echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
        Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
        <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
        </form>";
        $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE membros.id = "idmembro" AND membros.id = 2');
        for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
            include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
        }
    }if(in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){
        echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
        Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
        <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
        <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
        </form>";
        $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE membros.id = "idmembro" AND membros.id = 1');
        for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
            include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Ou seja, entendo que meu erro é verificar se Teste e Léo estão contidos em $_POST, mas como verificar se só Teste ou só Léo estão contidos?

Espero ter sido o mais claro possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez fosse o caso de simplificar usando elseif em todas as condições:

```
if(empty($array_membro)){
   echo("Você não selecionou nenhum membro.");
} elseif (in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"]) && in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){
   echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
   Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
   <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
   </form>";
   $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE (membros.id = 1 OR membros.id = 2)');
   for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
      include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
   }
} elseif (in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"])){
   echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
   Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
   <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
   </form>";
   $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE membros.id = "idmembro" AND membros.id = 2');
   for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
      include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
   }
} elseif (in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){
   echo "<form action='especifica_procura_dissertacao_publicacao_ordenada.php' method='POST'>
   Ordenar por:<br/><br/>
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='decrescente' /> Mais antigos
   <input type='checkbox' name='ordenarpor[]' value='crescente' /> Mais recentes
   <input type='submit' value='Pesquisar' />
   </form>";
   $result = pg_query('SELECT dissertacoes.titulo, dissertacoes.id, data, autor_nome, orientador, arquivo, autor_sobrenome, subtitulo, quant_folhas, area, local, instituicao, localizacao FROM dissertacoes, membros WHERE membros.id = "idmembro" AND membros.id = 1');
   for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i ++){
      include("chama_dissertacoes.php");
   }
}
```

Desta forma, apenas o primeiro bloco que atender às condições vai ser executado, excluindo os outros.

Outros pontos a revisar:

- `membros.id = "idmembro" AND membros.id = 2` nunca vai ser verdadeiro, e não trará resultados
- o bloco contido nos `elseif`s pode ser posto uma vez só no código, e as partes que mudam trocadas por `$variaveis`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"]) &&    in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){

}
elseif(in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"]) xor     in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){

    if(in_array("Teste",$_POST["membroarray"])){

    }

    elseif(in_array("Léo",$_POST["membroarray"])){

    }
}
```

[Referencia](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)